# NUnit Test project not finding any tests

Tags: c#, global-variables, nunit

I am new to NUnit testing and for some reason while trying to set up global variables, the program loses all references to all tests.  I think it's because I am trying to create a global variable the wrong way.  Any hint in the right direction would be helpful.

Here is a snipit of the code.

```
using System;
using JMS;
using System.IO;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace JMSTest {

    [TestFixture]
    public class JMSTests {

    private JMSForm testJMS { get { return new JMSForm(); } }
    private string[] goodFileList = new string[] { ".DLD", ".STA", ".TIF", ".DFC", ".PDF" };
    private string[] ignoreFileList = new string[] { ".INI", ".RBK" };
    
    [Test]
    public void TestCreateConnectionStringBlank() {
        string testString = testJMS.createConnectionString("", "", "", "");

        Assert.AreEqual(testString, "server=;database=;uid=;password=");
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestCreateConnectionStringProper() {
        string testString = testJMS.createConnectionString("1", "2", "3", "4");

        Assert.AreEqual(testString, "server=1;database=2;uid=3;password=4");
    }
```

The results I get is:

> ------ Discover test started ------
>
> ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.037) ==========

I have also tried

```
public class JMSTests {

    private static JMSForm testJMS;
    private static string[] goodFileList;
    private static string[] ignoreFileList;

    [SetUpFixture]
    public class before_tests_run {
        [SetUp]
        public void ControllerASetup() {
            var testJMS = new JMSForm();
            var goodFileList = new string[] { ".DLD", ".STA", ".TIF", ".DFC", ".PDF" };
            var ignoreFileList = new string[] { ".INI", ".RBK" };
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the answer you already got doesn't help, then come back and specify exactly what version of NUnit you are using and which test adapter you have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `NUnit3+` version, there is a new Test Adapter available.
Go to

> Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online" and search for "NUnit3 Test
>   Adapter

then install it. And then you will be able to run test.